# SwiftUI: How Can I Present A View Over All Views? (Especially Sheets)

Tags: swiftui

I want to show Image Viewer over all views when users tap into an image. It's working well without sheets but if there is a sheet on view, the image viewer stays behind it. How can I show image viewer over sheets too? I researched too much but I could not find any solution yet.

ContentView:

```
@ObservedObject var authVM: AuthVM = .shared

    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            TabView(selection: self.$authVM.selectedTab) {
                HomeTab()
                    .tabItem {
                        Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                            .renderingMode(.template)
                        Text("Home")
                    }.tag(SelectedTab.home)
                // Other tabs...
            }
            
            if self.authVM.showImageViewer{
                PhotoViewer(viewerImages: $authVM.images, currentPageIndex: $authVM.imageIndex)
                    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.vertical)
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm using SKPhotoBrowser pod (UIKit) with UIViewControllerRepresentable, maybe we can do something in UIKit to solve it?

```
    import SwiftUI
    import SKPhotoBrowser
    
    struct PhotoViewer: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
        
        @ObservedObject var authVM: AuthVM = .shared
        @Binding var viewerImages:[SKPhoto]
        @Binding var currentPageIndex: Int
    
        func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> SKPhotoBrowser {
            SKPhotoBrowserOptions.displayHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
            let browser = SKPhotoBrowser(photos: viewerImages)
            browser.initializePageIndex(currentPageIndex)
            browser.delegate = context.coordinator
            return browser
        }
    
        func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
            Coordinator(self)
        }
    
        func updateUIViewController(_ browser: SKPhotoBrowser, context: Context) {
            browser.photos = viewerImages
            browser.currentPageIndex = currentPageIndex
        }
    
        class Coordinator: NSObject, SKPhotoBrowserDelegate {
    
            var control: PhotoViewer
    
            init(_ control: PhotoViewer) {
                self.control = control
            }
    
            func didShowPhotoAtIndex(_ browser: PhotoViewer) {
                self.control.currentPageIndex = browser.currentPageIndex
            }
            
            func didDismissAtPageIndex(_ index: Int) {
                self.control.authVM.showImageViewer = false
            }
}
}
```

Comment: You're not showing any `sheet`s in your included code and there's not enough code here to reproduce anything. Have you tried `.fullScreenCover`?

Comment: The sheets are in the child views of tabs. Yes, I tried but it's not working with another sheet :( I got this error on terminal: EnvironmentKeyWritingModifierCSo22NSManagedObjectContext___: 0x7fa0b7818730>) which is already presenting

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example